# Scala Sbt error

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to run JAMR which needs Scala and SBT... 
However I ran into this problem when I tried to get sbt to work:

I have Scala installed and working:

This is what I get when I run Scala

```
reza@reza-ubi:~$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 
1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>
```

I downloaded the deb file and followed the quite simple instructions on the sbt page but

and when I run sbt:

```
reza@reza-ubi:~$ sbt
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.15  (this may take some time)...
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(JceSecurityManager.java:66)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2610)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2634)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isUnlimited(CipherSuite.java:602)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<init>(CipherSuite.java:574)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:354)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(SSLContextImpl.java:42)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:590)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1844)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1820)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:169)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:99)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:123)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:335)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1051)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.getURLInfo$57a0216e(BasicURLHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.getURLInfo(BasicURLHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLResource.init(URLResource.java:65)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLResource.exists(URLResource.java:81)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.findResourceUsingPattern(RepositoryResolver.java:97)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.findResourceUsingPatterns(AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.java:96)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.findIvyFileRef(IBiblioResolver.java:102)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:228)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.getDependency(IBiblioResolver.java:512)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.getDependency(ChainResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:169)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:714)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:594)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:234)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:99)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:352)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:208)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:216)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:216)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:118)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't read cryptographic policy directory: unlimited
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:324)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:73)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:109)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:106)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:105)
    ... 79 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
reza@reza-ubi:~$
```

All the version are up there.
How do I get it to work?
I'm trying run JAMR

Thank you

Comment: Are you using java 9?

Comment: What version of JDK are you using? Whats in your `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security`?

Comment: Your questions were the answer!
It seems that the default jdk was Java9 openjdk, I didn't have the Oracle Java 8 installed correctly (environment variables were not set, and it was not the default java)
once oracle java 8 was all set ... it worked...